# Hibernate - Mapping a model

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been stuck with this for quite a while now. I cannot map my model to with hibernate in hibernate.cfg.xml. I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: 
mainpackage.PersonModel
```

My Hibernate Config:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
```

```
<!-- These are not included in prod, prod profile uses jndi datasource -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect</property>

<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>

<mapping package="mainpackage"/>
<mapping class="mainpackage.PersonModel"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my model class:

```
package mainpackage;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "persondetails")
public class PersonModel implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "person_id", unique = true, nullable = false, length=5)
private int personId;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "second_name")
private String secondName;

public int getPersonId() {
    return personId;
}
public void setPersonId(int personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getSecondName() {
    return secondName;
}
public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have found a workaround by adding the following to my hibernate util class:

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
         configuration.configure();
         configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PersonModel.class);

How do I make it work using hibernate.cfg?

Comment: Post the complete code of the entity. From the package statement to the last line.

Comment: This is a compete code now. Thanks

Comment: No, it's not. This class wouldn't compile. It's missing import statements.

Comment: Sorry, have a look now

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace of the exception, the location of your config file, and the code causing the exception.